# How to make a enumerate list with numbers and given letter

Tags: enumerate

I would like to create a enumerate as following:

```
C1
 C1.1
 C1.2
C2
C3
```

Basically, all numbers have a given letter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `enumitem` you can define the first level list to have `label=C\arabic*`, which will prepend the `C` to the counter. for the following lists you can use `label*=.\arabic*`, which will append `.<counter>` to the parent list counter.

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=C\arabic*]
  \item item
  \begin{enumerate}[label*=.\arabic*]
    \item sub item
    \item another sub item
  \end{enumerate}
  \item another item
  \item one more item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

If you want this to be the global setting of your document, instead of using `\begin{enumerate}[label...` every time (which can be quite tedious and error-prone), you can use `\setlist`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[1]{label=C\arabic*}
\setlist{label*=.\arabic*}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item item
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item sub item
    \item another sub item
  \end{enumerate}
  \item another item
  \item one more item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The first `\setlist` will make `C<counter>` for first level lists, and the second will append `.<counter>` to the other levels.